Foundation sliding in, basement flooding, sediment seeping in between basement wall and foundation
I have sandy sediment and water seeping out from between my basement wall and foundation. and the basement walls appear to be sliding in. Please help.
PHOTOS
Photos are of the left side basement wall. The marked photo shows where I believe the previous owners poured the wall solid with concrete. The basement wall is pushed in from the foundation up to 1.5" right near where this leak is emanating from. I can actually reach my fingers around underneath and feel the inside of the cinderblock just outside that marked area so I know it isn't solid. The roof slopes down the front and back of the house so there is no gutter on this side of the house. I'm not sure If I'd really be able to dig down very effectively on the exterior as the AC unit is almost right above this from what I can tell. I don't see any obvious water pooling or anything of note on the exterior.
Bought the house almost 4 years ago. House was built in 1965. Home inspector noticed bowed walls and previous owner advised that they had repair done to mitigate the bowing and water ingress. Some of the walls appeared to be possible poured solid with concrete (uncertain), all the walls are Drylok'd, French drain all around, sump pump in the corner, and extra large gutters outside. Structural engineer came in at closing and recommended the walls be poured solid with concrete at leas 2 feet from the bottom on both the bowed walls. Also recommended 2x4 lateral bracing from the first floor joists to the basement walls to support the top. I have yet to do this.
About 2 years ago the sump pump failed and I had the whole basement flood about 4 inches deep completely submerged. I replaced the sump pump and have since not had any issues ( I can hear the sump pump constantly working every rain storm) until one day ago. My roommate noticed the sand sediment on the wall pictured above. There was only about 1-2 hours of moderate rain the previous night. Tonight we had another hour or so of heavy rain and even more sandy sediment leaked through. The sump pump still appears to be working as far as I can tell.
I thought the only shining light in this very stormy night of mine was that I couldn't find any new cracks in the basement wall, but I ended up finding vertical cracks in the wall just to the right of where this leak is occurring (photos above) and after referring to the engineers notes it looks like he measured 1.25" on this wall, between the base of the wall and the foundation. After digging through all the sandy sediment, it appears I can fit about 1.75" of my tape measure under this wall now, about a foot to the right of the leak. This 1.75" is actually about a foot to the right of where the leak is.
My question for all of you. How screwed am I? With a sump pump a few feet away and a French drain already installed, what can I do? Right above this leak outside is the AC unit. I have no Idea how easy that would be to temporarily disconnect so I could dig down and try to find the source of this leak. Or if I could dig around it some how. But with all the mitigating factors the previous owners have already taken, I'm wondering if this is just a bad area to be living for ground water. There must be a ton of pressure outside to push all this sand through.
I'm thinking I'll at least do what the structural engineer recommended and pour the walls solid with concrete and reinforce the top. but what else can I do for the water leaking? Any ideas and knowledge dumps would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT I added photos of the exterior of the home right above where this leak is occurring. Thank you for the advise, I will now add some landscaping to my plans, add a few truck fulls of dirt to this area and angle things away. The leak isn't directly below the AC unit like I thought either, so I should be able to dig down and investigate. I was also thinking of drilling holes on the exterior of the home, maybe 6 inches in diameter to pour the concrete in from the top so I can fill the whole wall solid in this area.

Tell us more about your French drain—it is the type where they trench through the concrete slab in the basement, or the type where they trench outside the perimeter of the house?

I believe it is trenched through the concrete slab in the basement but I don't know for sure. It looks like they just cut about 2 inches out from the wall in the basement slab all around and filled it with gravel, and the chunks of concrete they cut away it looks like. I doubt they dug down on the outside to trench anything.

For reducing water ingress: The simple things too often ignored: Make sure the ground all around the house slopes away from the house (1% minimum slope - 1/8" per foot) for at least 10-12 feet all around the house. Change the landscaping if needed to achieve this. Be sure those "extra large gutters" are clear (not overflowing in storms) and the downspouts are taking the water far away from the house.
Vastly more expensive and with considerable variation depending on overall terrain is to dig down and place exterior drainage pipes to remove water. If the land is sloped that can drain by gravity, otherwise you get into needing exterior sump pumps with sump wells for them to live in. Speaking of sump pumps, be sure that the drain from the interior one is going far enough away from the house.
Moving your A/C unit is typically difficult/expensive as you'll need to have a licensed refrigeration tech recover the refrigerant and seal things up so it can be moved, first.
How much this helps when you've left the structural problem to get worse for 4 years, unknown. Might be time to invest in a revisit by the engineer...

You might be able to avoid moving the AC if you start your huge trench a couple feet away from it. All sites are different, so ymmv.
